# oracle apex switch theme error "This application cannot be converted to a theme using list-based navigation"

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I am migrating apex code from 4.2 to 5.0. Before we used the theme "Light Blue - 15" and now in order to use the navigation menu feature, we want to switch theme to "Universal Theme - 42".

When switching, one error window popped up and said "**This application cannot be converted to a theme using list-based navigation, as it uses two levels of tabs. Please update the application and set current tabs settings to use only one level of tabs prior to switching the theme.**"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjvAQ.jpg)

Then I checked my app current theme "Light Blue - 15" and it said this is one level tabs customized:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jlM4.png)

Is there anything wrong? Can you give me some help on how to resolve this kind of error?

Comment: Your second screenshot is misleading you - that's just the name of the default page template, which can be anything (just because it says "One Level Tabs customised" doesn't mean it's actually using one level). I think you need to review what page templates have been used by your application - you may find one or more pages have been set to one of the Two Level Tabs templates. Modify those pages to use a One Level Tab page template, then see if you can upgrade. You may also need to review your tabsets.

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this problem and it was kinda hard to research -- all answers were vague or just plain wrong.

APEX does not allow switching to Universal theme until all parent tabs are gone. You have to delete all of them and then you'll be able to switch your current theme to Universal. During import operation APEX turns all your tabs into a long list. Then add new parent items to that list and rebuild your menu tree.

Answer (score -1):

You will not be able to make this switch. If you wish to use "Universal theme - 42" you will need to write your app in that theme from the ground up.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. And how to check the tabs is one level  or two levels? I am wondering to check it from the current theme. Is it correct?

Comment: No. I was able to migrate to Universal theme from an old two-level app. I had to delete all parent tabs and then apex allowed me to change theme to Universal.